# Python3 error "no module named bluetooth" on Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, module, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my Lenovo S10E to a Nintendo Wiimote via bluetooth. I am using a simple Python script, reproduced below. I am calling it from the Linux Mint (version 16, "Petra") command line using `python3 find_wii.py`

Script:

```
import bluetooth

target_name = "Nintendo RVL-CNT-01"
target_address = "00:1C:BE:29:75:7F"

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
    print("found target bluetooth device with address "), target_address
else:
    print("could not find target bluetooth device nearby")
```

I am receiving the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_wii.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bluetooth
ImportError: No module named 'bluetooth'
```

I have installed bluez and python wrappings for it (`sudo aptitude install python-bluez`). I have upgraded my system (`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`). I did consulted Google, and the only official bugs I could find are [here](https://code.google.com/p/remuco/issues/detail?id=137) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/issues/detail?id=36), and neither of the answers worked for me.

How can I get the Bluetooth module to work?

Comment: BTW, this is wrong (for Python 3 at least): `print("found target bluetooth device with address "), target_address`

Comment: @otus, thanks for catching that!

Comment: It looks like you've edited that script from [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c212.html) where `target_address` was initialized to `None`. Were this a function, `target_name` would be a parameter, but `target_address` would not; it would be a working variable and eventual return value. This code discovers that address for the user; you're not supposed to fill it in yourself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've installed the Python 2 version of the bluez bindings. Either run the script using `python2` or install the Python 3 bindings. Since they aren't packaged, you would need to install them using pip:

```
python3 -m pip install pybluez
```

Comment: This gave me `ImportError: libbluetooth.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` which was fixed by `sudo apt-get install libbluetooth3`. Debian 9.0 on 4.14.94

Comment: you @otus have saved my noobie life.

Answer (score 34):

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth libbluetooth-dev
sudo python3 -m pip install pybluez
```

This worked for me on raspberry pi 3.

Comment: This worked without either of the `bluetooth`, `libbluetooth-dev` packages, but with a dependency of the latter - `libbluetooth3` - instead. Debian 9.0 on 4.14.94

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.3 after ```sudo pip3 install pybluez``` and ```pip3 install pybluez``` caused the following error:  ```bluez/btmodule.h:5:10: fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory```.

Comment: It works for me and raspberry device bluetooth and wi-fi config module.

Answer (score 3):

with *Ubuntu 16.04*, I had the same issue. I installed **pybluez** and that fixed the import issue. I installed it using:

```
sudo pip3 install pybluez
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: `error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.`

Comment: @TiagoRangel, Install PyBluez from the github, look this question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818465/pybluez-error-in-pybluez-setup-command-use-2to3-is-invalid