# PyBluez: error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid

Tags: python, pip, pybluez

I am trying to `pip install pybluez` and I get this error:

```
Collecting PyBluez
  Using cached PyBluez-0.23.tar.gz (97 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

How do I solve this?

Edit:
Turns out its not being updated for windows so I just switched to a linux vb

Comment: This started happening to me in recent pip installations and I honestly don't like it. Anyway, try downgrading your pip.

Comment: For package specific issues, using their issue tracker can help - they have [resolved this issue](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/413) in their source but has not packaged it for PyPI.  Searching further will point you to [this comment](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/431#issuecomment-1107884273) about how to install the latest source release which should workaround this issue.

Comment: This is a known issue, _with_ a known solution. https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/431#issuecomment-1107884273. This is why the posting guidelines start with telling you to [search and research](/help/how-to-ask) before posting =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpybluez%5D+error+in+setup+command%3A+use_2to3+is+invalid

Answer (score 14):

As [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818465/cant-install-pybluez#comment133740913_75818465), you can solve this by installing the package from source:

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git#egg=pybluez
```

Indeed,

> The pypi version is outdated and this issue is fixed in the dev
> version ages ago.
>
> Source: [This answer was provided by dogtopus on a GitHub issue of the pybluez repository.](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/431#issuecomment-1107884273)